# EIP pattern for synchronously processing different messages (in different queues) that affect same logical record?

Tags: apache-camel, messaging

I have several inbound messages that pertain to the same record. They arrive and are brokered out to different queues. Is there an EIP pattern that would allow me to process only one of those at a time, even though they're in different queues?

Thanks.

Comment: Can I know why would you need such a scenario. As many of the scenarios need many threads to work and all the messages needs to be processed in parallel?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I'll be getting different messages regarding different parts of data for the same logical entity. There might be a need to process these in a particular order, like resequencing, but they would be in different queues.

Answer (score 2):

You could funnel the queues into a SEDA queue:

```
  from("jms:queue:queueA").to("seda:handler");
  from("jms:queue:queueB").to("seda:handler");
  from("jms:queue:queueC").to("seda:handler");

  from("seda:handler").log("processing...");
```